# Finding supremum of a set; am I underdoing it?

Tags: real-analysis

> Find, with proof, the supremum of the subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}$ defined by:
>
> $E = \left\{\frac{25+16\sqrt{n}}{5+3\sqrt{n}}:n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$

Is it ok to solve the limit of the function and call it a proof?

i.e. $$\text{sup}(E) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f(n) =\space ...$$

Or do I need to involve actual definitions of bounds etc.

Comment: In general, limit may not give you the supremum. For example, consider $\left\{\frac{1}{n}\right\}$, the limit as $n \to \infty$ is $0$ but the supremum is $1$.

Comment: $\frac{25+16\sqrt{n}}{5+3\sqrt{n}}=\frac{16}3-\frac5{15+9\sqrt{n}}$

Comment: If you prove it is increasing you can do that.  But you should cite the theorem that says you can do that.

Comment: Out of curiosity just how would you claim to limit?  Whatever argument you use to declare a limit are basically the same, in this case, as declaring the supremum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an increasing sequence

$$ \left\{\frac{25+16\sqrt{n}}{5+3\sqrt{n}}:n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$$

with the limit as $n$ goes to infinity equal to $16/3$

The limit is the supremum, that is $$\sup (E) = 16/3$$
All you have to do is to show that the sequence is increasing and bounded above by its limit.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
As I pointed out in my comment, in general, the limit may not be the answer for supremum.

In this problem, observe that
$$\frac{25+16\sqrt{n}}{5+3\sqrt{n}}=5+\frac{1}{3+\frac{5}{\sqrt{n}}}.$$
So the given sequence is an increasing sequence (you still need to show boundedness, which is easy). So the limit will, give you the supremum.

*But simply computing the limit is not a proof that supremum is what you claim it to be.*

Answer (score 0):

The supremum is the limit if the function in question is increasing. Doing some reduction shows

$$\frac{25+15\sqrt{n}}{5+3\sqrt{n}}=5+\frac{\sqrt{n}}{5+3\sqrt{n}}=
5+\frac{1}{
\frac{5}{\sqrt{n}}+3
}$$
which is clearly an increasing function of $n$. The supremum/limit of this function at natural number values is $5+1/3=16/3.$